# (html) how to stop button from moving

Tags: html, css, button

So basically I have this button on the left side..

```
<button class="btn"> button1 </button><br /> <br>
```

When I add text in the middle of the page.. the button moves down

I want to keep the button where it is on the left side of the page vertically, and not have it effected by me adding stuff in the center of the page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please provide the code of what you have done

Comment: use  css `clear:both`. =_= and always come here with some of codes or a live preview link

Comment: Absolute positioning should do the trick.

Comment: @GautamJha `clear:both` clears float attribute. Why would it be relevant in this context?

Comment: @Awol - I think `clear` should work because button changing its position when he add some text, earlier sometimes i got same problem with contents. do you think i am wrong?

Comment: @shubhamkhandelwal this is literally all I have... besides one <p>

Comment: @GautamJha - Well, `clear` is relevant when an element's position is affected by floating elements (whether to shift it down below the floating elements). Refer the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear). In this case, there are no floating elements specified, so the `clear` attribute would not affect the button at all

Comment: @Ofcdan - What shubhamkhandelwal meant is that you should include a working snippet so that the viewers can understand and visualize your problem. Try including an HTML/CSS snippet in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use **class="clearfix"** to parent element (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/), this may help you.

```
.clearfix:after {
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
font-size: 0;
content: " ";
clear: both;
height: 0;
}
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the button absolute, remove the line-brake()
 button1 
    .btn 
    {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      margin:auto;
    }